# C++ library API. Using converter classes instead of plain C api

Tags: c++, api, stl, interop, portability

This question is about C++ <-> C++ interoperability.

As is well known implementation of standard library classes/functions may differ across different vendors. Moreover implementation may differ even within same library vendor, when using different compiler keys, configuration (Debug/Release), etc.

Due to that reason, many library developers shifts to old plain C-style API.
Which leads to uglish error-prone interfaces.

For instance, in order to get string from some function, interfaces like Win GetCurrentDirectory function are used:

```
DWORD WINAPI GetCurrentDirectory(
  __in   DWORD nBufferLength,
  __out  LPTSTR lpBuffer
);
```

three parameters + some boilerplate code on both sides(checking if buffer size was enough, etc) just to get simple string.

I am thinking to use some auxiliary adapter/proxy class, which will do all conversions automaticly, and can be simply reused.

Something like:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

class StringConverter
{
    char *str; // TODO: use smart pointer with right deleter
public:
    StringConverter(const std::string &user_string) // Will be defined only at user side
    {
        str=new char[user_string.length()+1];
        (*(std::copy(user_string.begin(),user_string.end(),str)))=0;
    }
    operator std::string() // Will be defined only at library side
    {
        return std::string(str);
    }
    ~StringConverter()
    {
        delete [] str;
    }
};

StringConverter foo()
{
    return std::string("asd");
}


int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << std::string(foo()) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/EfcKv

Note, I plan to have defenition of conversion from user string to StringConverter only at user side, and defenition of conversion from StringConverter to library string only inside library.
Also, right deleter should be used (from right heap).

What do you think about such approach?

Are there some major pitfalls?

Are there some superior alternatives?

Comment: Your code violates the rule of three, and has no apparent purpose. Please show an example.

Comment: "violates the rule of three" - yes, I know, it is just for demonstration.

Comment: "no apparent purpose", reread my question, see where conversions are defined. Hint: different std::string implementations

Comment: "violates the rule of three" And by the way, some smart-pointer(I already said that it is needed) - will solve that problem.

Comment: What is this supposed to achieve? Instead of passing a `std::string` across the API boundary, which I can't do because of ABI incompatibility, I should instead pass a `StringConverter`, which suffers from the exact same problem?

Comment: Why do you think it suffers? Note, user can not invoke "operator std::string()" because it is not defined at user side. Library can not invoke StringConverter(const std::string &user_string)

Comment: Moreover, if you are embarrassed that std::string is used at both conversions, then it is possible to use something like type tags, in order to have "true" distinct types.

Comment: It's unclear to me, at least.

Comment: @cds, what is exactly unclear to you?

Comment: Well, in the cold light of day, it makes more sense today than yesterday.  Have you tested this?  Does it actually interoperate correctly?  I'm also curious, if you have enough control to alter both the user and library side interfaces, why don't you have enough control to get them to agree on a compiler?

Comment: @cds, I didn't make real test. I don't see a reason why it should not work. In most "worst" case, conversion operator and copy constructor can be just forwarders to stand-alone functions, what I think makes implementation very straightforward - without visible pitfalls. However, I agree - I should make some real test case - I will try when will have time.

Comment: @cds, Regaridng "same compiler" - during development of commercial library, when you want to pass std::string around, you have to use same compiler, same stdlib, even same compile options on both sides. Now, imagine that multiplicity when you have clients who use different compiler versions, different stdlib implementations - then you literally have to provide MANY different builds of library using same toolchain to build - or you will lose money. And basically, that is the path which is chosen by many commercial libraries - they just provide tens of different builds.

Comment: @cds, another path is to use plain C-style api - with much of bug-prone boilerplate. But wait, client side knows how to convert it's std::string to plain C stuff, library side knows how make some reasonable std::string from plain C stuff - why not just use such automatic conversions with help of special converter/wrapper classes? Without bloating of interfaces with plain C API

Comment: @john That gave me the key piece I was missing.  It wasn't clear (to me) that you were providing a commercial library for use by many clients and their various compilers and such.  This mechanism clearly adds complexity and ugliness, but given your situation, I can see how this should be less complex (and maybe less ugly?) than the alternatives.  At least assuming it works and no one proposes a cleaner solution... :-)

Comment: So, I would summarize your plan as follows:  You're worried mostly about standard library compatibility and maybe compatibility of non-basic features of the language between compilers.  You are not worried about the simple parts of the language needed to represent StringConverter interoperably.  As such, you have the library's side of the conversion compiled into it and the user code's portion is provided via the exported headers and the user's compiler compiles it into their application.  The interchange interface is the function/method calling scheme and the representation of StringConverter

Comment: ...and any similar wrapper classes, I suppose.  It makes sense to me now... :-)

Answer (score 0):

This technique will work in some cases where standard data types are incompatible, but in others it will fare no better: name mangling differences and class memory layout differences (vptrs and tags) come to mind.

This is why C APIs are preferred.

But you *can* improve usability by burying the C API where the library caller never needs to see it. Then add a thin, idiomatic C++ overlay that provides the visible library interface. In some cases the thin overlay code can be used on both caller and library side, each compiled in its own environment: flags, link conventions, etc.  Only C data types are exchanged.  The simpler these data types are, the more compatibility you'll obtain.

The layer also takes care that memory allocation and deallocation occur on the same side of the API on a per object basis, as your code does.  But it can be more flexible.  For example, it's possible to arrange for an object allocated in the caller to be deallocated in the library and vice versa.

```
// library.h for both caller and library

// "shadow" C API should not be used by caller
extern "C" {
void *make_message(char *text);
char *get_text_of_message(void* msg);
void send_message(void *msg); // destroys after send.
}

// Thin C++ overlay
class Message {
  void *msg;
public:

  Message(const std::string &text) {
    msg = make_message(text.c_str());
  }

  void send() {
    if (msg) send_message(msg);
    else error("already sent");
    msg = 0;
  }

  std:string getTextString() {
    return std:string(get_text_of_message(void* msg));
  }
}
```

Comment: "name mangling differences and class memory layout differences (vptrs and tags) come to mind."- I use very small subset of C++ for conversion class. It is possible to go even further and put all internal data of conversion class into aggregated POD struct member. If you need to pass deleter, it is possible to store it in POD struct as function pointer. There is no need for vtables. As the result ABI requirenments are very low. I can afford a little ABI requirenments trading-off some compatability. In any case it is better than doing tens of different builds.

Comment: "But you can improve usability by burying the C API where the library caller never needs to see it." - Well, I want to eliminate need for doing boilerplate code on both sides. It is tedious and error-prone to manually wrap each each function three times by hands: first at the middle - plain C, second at user side, and third at library side. Instead of this I am thinking about wrapping only some types into *Converter classes - and as the result you may use many different such types as function parameters, without need to wrap EACH such function THREE times.

Comment: If it would be some automatic tool for generate wrappers around each function - that will change situation, but currently I don't know such tool. Closest thing I have in mind is SWIG, but it does not do C++ <-> C++ stuff.

Comment: @John Well it's obvious that you used a simple C++ class. I have not done C++ for a while, but when I did, you could not compile even your simple class with Borland C++, g++, and MSC and have any 2 of them link. The names were mangled differently. My method would work because the C calling conventions were the same.  NB: Adding C++ to C++ to SWIG would not be such a big job.

Comment: Even if I would need to do builds for major copilers, without need to make many builds within one compiler family - that would be a big win. As I said, I can afford this tradeoff.  "My method would work because the C calling conventions were the same" What is "your" method? Plain C-api, manualy wrapping each function? I knew about it - it is not acceptable.  "NB: Adding C++ to C++ to SWIG would not be such a big job" - well, I need it now, do you know some ready-to-use tools?

Comment: I have some other ideas, but you seem more interested in validating your own, so I give up.

Comment: If these ideas also involve boilerplate code for EACH function - I don't need it too.